# Indenting the rows of a table at various level(length) using LYX

Tags: indentation

I have to create a long-table having more than 200 rows and rows are indent at various lengths(levels), there is a button in Lyx for indentation but that don't work. Example is here

```
`%% LyX 2.0.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% define lightgray
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

% alternate rowcolors for all long-tables
\let\oldlongtable\longtable
\let\endoldlongtable\endlongtable
\renewenvironment{longtable}{\rowcolors{2}{white}{lightgray}\oldlongtable} {
\endoldlongtable}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lc}
\hline 
\textbf{SECURITY} & \textbf{CODE}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\endhead
\textbf{I. Gold Bullion,Ornaments,Precious Metals} & \textbf{0000}\tabularnewline
\textbf{II. Sec.,Shares And Other Financial Instruments} & \tabularnewline
 (A)1. To Stock Brokers and Dealers & \tabularnewline
     A) Govt. \& Others Trustee Securities-Quoted & 1001\tabularnewline
     B) Shares and Debentures-Quoted & 1002\tabularnewline
     C) Participation Term Certificates-Quoted & 1003\tabularnewline
     D) Others-Quoted & 1009\tabularnewline
 (A)2. To Others & \tabularnewline
     A) Govt. \& Other Trustee Securities-Quoted & 1011\tabularnewline
     B) Shares and Debentures-Quoted & 1012\tabularnewline
     C) Participation Term Certificates-Quoted & 1013\tabularnewline
     D) Others-Quoted & 1019\tabularnewline

\hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

'
Desired output should be look like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to use two columns and use `\multicolumn{2}{l}{<text>}` to have the `<text>` span two columns. The indented text start in the second column hence requires a `&` at the start:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter

\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% define lightgray
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

% alternate rowcolors for all long-tables
\let\oldlongtable\longtable
\let\endoldlongtable\endlongtable
\renewenvironment{longtable}{\rowcolors{2}{white}{lightgray}\oldlongtable} {
\endoldlongtable}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{llc}
\hline 
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{SECURITY}} & \textbf{CODE}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\endhead
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{I. Gold Bullion,Ornaments,Precious Metals}} & \textbf{0000}\tabularnewline
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{II. Sec.,Shares And Other Financial Instruments}} & \tabularnewline
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{(A)1. To Stock Brokers and Dealers} & \tabularnewline
     & A) Govt. \& Others Trustee Securities-Quoted & 1001\tabularnewline
     & B) Shares and Debentures-Quoted & 1002\tabularnewline
     & C) Participation Term Certificates-Quoted & 1003\tabularnewline
     & D) Others-Quoted & 1009\tabularnewline
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{(A)2. To Others} & \tabularnewline
     & A) Govt. \& Other Trustee Securities-Quoted & 1011\tabularnewline
     & B) Shares and Debentures-Quoted & 1012\tabularnewline
     & C) Participation Term Certificates-Quoted & 1013\tabularnewline
     & D) Others-Quoted & 1019\tabularnewline

\hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: to see visually, import the code in Lyx.